# Comparing hashed passwords with PHP in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, md5, salt, password-hash

I am building a external application for which user login credentials will be taken from WordPress site database table.In the table i can see that passwords are being hashed and resemble to something like this

> $P$9jWFhEPMfI.KPByiNO9IyUzSTG7EZK0

My requirement is to check this password against the plain password in login.I am using a function `$hashed=wp_hash_password($password);` in order to generate a hash and compare it against the one stored in db.But this generated a random hash every time for the same password.So how can i compare the two passwords?Also i can see in my wp_config different salt values are defined like AUTH_SALT,SECURE_AUTH_SALT,LOGGED_IN_SALT,NONCE_SALT

Please suggest a way to compare the hashed passwords.Do we need to use any of these salts to get it right.If so please suggest some sample code

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3):

You should use **wp_check_password( string $password, string $hash, string|int $user_id= '' )**

> $password (string) (Required) Plaintext user's password
>
> $hash (string) (Required) Hash of the user's password to check
>   against.
>
> $user_id (string|int) (Optional) User ID.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_check_password/

Comment: what is $hash?is it retrieved from db or the hash we do using wp_hash_password(plain password)?

Comment: The hashed password that you take directly from the db.